# Unable to access location in Android device (Access denied, error code 3, no location provider available)

Tags: geolocation, react-native

I am trying to access location.
I have tried with both
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service and
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation

How can this be solved? Is it something wrong with setup? or anything wrong with my code? Though I searched a lot about this and gone through all the solutions which couldn't help.
Also tried linking manually even though auto-linking is enabled in this version. But could not solve the issue.
Is there any other module to fetch location?

I have included below lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

My React configuration

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
```

react-native-community/geolocation: ^2.0.2

If I turn on my location manually in mobile phone it will fetch location. And able to get location in android emulator.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import {
    withTheme,
    Appbar,
} from 'react-native-paper';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
// import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import RNAndroidLocationEnabler from 'react-native-android-location-enabler';

class AddBill extends Component {
    state = {
        initialposition: [],
        latitude: '',
        logitude: '',
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("test")
            let config = {
                authorizationLevel: "auto"
            }
            Geolocation.setRNConfiguration(config);
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    console.log(position);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                },
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 110000 }
            );
        } else {
            console.log('Location permission not granted!!!!');
        }
    };

    _back = () => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <Appbar.Header>
                    <Appbar.BackAction onPress={this._back} />
                    <Appbar.Content title="New Bill" />
                </Appbar.Header>
                <View></View>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default withTheme(AddBill);
```

[image]

react-native-geolocation-service: ^5.0.0

Same error after turning on location manually

[image]

Comment: can you share the whole code for  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition( and all its part including imports

Comment: @GauravRoy I have added the code, please check

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your MainApplication.java and then make a build and try

```
import com.agontuk.RNFusedLocation.RNFusedLocationPackage;
```

// add new RNFusedLocationPackage() in

```
@override
protected List getPackages() {
return Arrays.asList(
new RNFusedLocationPackage()

        );
    }
```

Comment: Already included the above lines, but manually linking is not required for 0.60 and above right.. Anyway it didn't work for me

Comment: oh, you have made a new build and tried on that right?

Comment: yes, I did try all the options available on internet too :(

Comment: very weird case, then if you have tried all, ill suggest raising an issue on their github repo.

Comment: yes it looks correct, code there aint a problem, its probably with native modules of library